# How to push and pull to repository from forked repository

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have a Github repository, lets call it Repo A. I have two other users than need to push/pull changes from this repository. How do I go about doing this?
I have tried having one of the other users fork Repo A into their own Repo, lets call it Repo B, but when they make changes to the contents, it only pushes to Repo B, not Repo A. 
I want the other users to have the changes they make locally push to Repo A.

Comment: Then have them clone directly from Repo A.

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood version control at all. If you want other people to push changes to the same repo, why are they creating forks?

Comment: So other people can just clone from Repo A, and pull/push changes? Will they need the login information for the owner of Repo A, or can they use their own login info?

Comment: @JasonCromer you can either share credentials or (better) add their accounts as contributors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you!

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you write this as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Forget forks. [Use branches](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/). This is the simpler option. Everyone involved needs access to the repo.
2. Keep forks, [use Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/). This allows the owner of the repo to fully control whether changes are accepted or rejected.

Comment: Ok, I will give this a try and let you know the results.